# What does Promise<OverlayEventDetail<any>> mean?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I got this code from the `components.d.ts` file of `@ionic/core/dist/type`:

```
 'onDidDismiss': () => Promise<OverlayEventDetail<any>>
```

What does `<>` mean in the code?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a `generic` and allows for methods/classes to accept a variety of types, not just a single one to make components more generic and consumable.

Read up on the [concept of generics here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

In your example `'onDidDismiss': () => Promise<OverlayEventDetail<any>>` means, that `onDidDismiss` is a `function` that returns a `Promise` of type `OverlayEventDetail`, which again has the "inner" type of `any`.